# Sudden java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in IntelliJ 2016.3.4

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

Yesterday my application worked fine but when I try to start it today through IntelliJ, I simply get this error:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41617', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.company.app.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41617', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It's a Spring Boot (1.5.1) app built with Gradle (3.4.1). When I invoke `gradle bootRun` the app starts without hassle. 
I already tried re-importing from scratch (deleting the whole directory and git clone it freshly) and deleting the local `.gradle` directory. In total, two applications are not working anymore but without any code changes since yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, there seems to be a bug in IntelliJ 2016.3.4 which is not working well together with Gradle 3.4 according to Jetbrain's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168710

Solution: Either upgrade to IntelliJ 2017 (EAP at time of writing) or downgrade to Gradle 3.3.

Downgrading Gradle is very easy, just type `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=3.3` inside your project.

Comment: Where do I type this please

Comment: @olyjosh on the terminal, inside the root directory of your project.  This assumes you have a gradlew executable in there

Comment: thanks ,,, I upgradle Intellij Idea to 2018 and my problem resolved :)